# AWS lambda from MSK cluster missing kafka message header

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, amazon-msk

I want to use AWS lambda to consumer kafka messages, but the events I received don't contain kafka headers, that are very critical. Is there a way to get messages with headers info?

Comment: Is that headers available in messages in kafka? or no headers in kafka also?

Comment: Is this solved? I see same behavior. The headers are there in kafka. Other consumers are able to receive headers

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda Kafka integration did not support headers before, but they have (very recently, in the last few days) silently added support for headers. You can see this in the latest event example in the docs (or try it yourself): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-msk.html

Comment: but it came in encoded form: `"headerKey": [1,2,3,4..]`. It is a list of integers, corresponding to each character an integer number. It is not clear how to compare lists, how to trigger lambda only on specific list taking into account the order of elements.